# an element $a$ in a unital algebra is left invertible iff $ann_r(a)=\{0\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a unital algebra and let $a\in A$. I'm reading a text which seems to claim that the following asserstions are equivalent:

a) $a$ is left invertible (i.e., there is an element $b\in A$ such that $ba=1$).

b) $ann_r(a)=\{0\}$. Where $ann_r(a):=\{x\in A: ax=0\}$ is the subsapce of right annihilators of $a$.

I know that a) implies b) because if $ax=0$, then $b(ax)=(ba)x=1x=x=b0=0$, i.e., $x=0$. Could anyone explain why b) implies a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication (b) implies (a) isn't true in general.

Consider the field $\mathbb{C}$ and the unital (commutative) algebra $\mathbb{C}[x]$ of polynomials in the variable $x$.  First, note that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is an integral domain, so in particular $ann(f) = \{0\}$ for every $0 \neq f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. However, by comparing degrees, one can show that if $fg=1$ then $f$ and $g$ are both constants (ie, have degree $0$).  Thus, for a concrete example, the polynomial $x$ has $ann(x) = \{0\}$ but $x$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.